# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(\sin x)^{n+1}}{e^{nx^2}} $

Tags: real-analysis

I have found puntual convergence in all $R$.
For the uniform convergence I would use Weierstrass rule.Have I to separate the cases for $|x|>1$ and $|x|<1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{n+1} (x)}{e^{nx^2}}=\sin(x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^n (x)}{e^{nx^2}}=\sin(x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{e^{x^2}} \right)^n$$

Comment: Is it a geometric series?